# Gstreamer preserve timestamp when encoding ts segments

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming, hls.js

I have a series of ts files(h265) which are part of a m3u8 manifest which are fed into the pipeline through fdsrc. I use the following pipeline to transcode them to H264 to be played on a Hlsjs web browser.

```
cat 2021-06-30T00-55-41Z_2000000.ts | gst-launch-1.0  -q mpegtsmux name=mux ! fdsink fd=1 fdsrc ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! h265parse ! nvh265dec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=640,height=360 ! nvh264enc ! mux.
```

The individual ts segments are transcoded successfully and can be played.

However the DTS is out of aligment and when these ts segments are played as part of the hls manifest, it is not able to play as DTS is out of order.

```
[mpegts @ 0x7fb69100a400] DTS 6496420096 < 6496446847 out of order
[hls @ 0x7fb69580ea00] DTS 6496420096 < 6496446847 out of order
```

In FFMPEG we have copyts to preserve the timestamp.
Is there something similar in gstreamer to preserve the timestamp? Or atleast generate a timestamp with the current time so that the player doesnt complain?

I tried `fdsrc do-timestamp=true` but that didnt work.

I appreciate any help in this.

Best

Comment: Same issue. Have you figured it out?

Comment: The only way to do it in gstreamer is to have the entire series of ts segments that we want to transcode at once. I have changed the pipeline to move it entirely in gstreamer. I have a condition where I need to have them individually transcoded (add contents from other sources). For that I insert #DISCONTINUITY tag to make them work in the hlsjs player. Hope it helps.